# Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.xxx.CartoonActivity.access$super in android 4.4.2

Tags: android, android-studio

**hey guys!
 I'm losing my mind. I have a custom gridview class that I have put it inside a scrollview. I have no problem in devices with android +5, but in some devices I got this error:**

```
08-25 01:24:56.890 6673-6673/com.ablazephoenix.mycartoon E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.ablazephoenix.mycartoon.CartoonActivity.access$super
08-25 01:24:56.890 6673-6673/com.ablazephoenix.mycartoon W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 296 (Landroid/os/PersistableBundle;) in Lcom/ablazephoenix/mycartoon/CartoonActivity;
08-25 01:24:56.890 6673-6673/com.ablazephoenix.mycartoon D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x00fc
08-25 01:24:56.890 6673-6673/com.ablazephoenix.mycartoon I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getColorStateList, referenced from method com.ablazephoenix.mycartoon.CartoonActivity.access$super
08-25 01:24:56.890 6673-6673/com.ablazephoenix.mycartoon W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 688: Landroid/content/Context;.getColorStateList (I)Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList;
08-25 01:24:56.890 6673-6673/com.ablazephoenix.mycartoon D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x010c
08-25 01:24:56.890 6673-6673/com.ablazephoenix.mycartoon I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.onVisibleBehindCanceled, referenced from method com.ablazephoenix.mycartoon.CartoonActivity.access$super
08-25 01:24:56.890 6673-6673/com.ablazephoenix.mycartoon W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 294: Landroid/app/Activity;.onVisibleBehindCanceled ()V
08-25 01:24:56.890 6673-6673/com.ablazephoenix.mycartoon D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x011c
08-25 01:24:56.890 6673-6673/com.ablazephoenix.mycartoon I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.ContextWrapper.deleteSharedPreferences, referenced from method com.ablazephoenix.mycartoon.CartoonActivity.access$super
08-25 01:24:56.890 6673-6673/com.ablazephoenix.mycartoon W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 749: Landroid/content/ContextWrapper;.deleteSharedPreferences (Ljava/lang/String;)Z
08-25 01:24:56.890 6673-6673/com.ablazephoenix.mycartoon D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0126
08-25 01:24:56.890 6673-6673/com.ablazephoenix.mycartoon I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method com.ablazephoenix.mycartoon.CartoonActivity.access$super
08-25 01:24:56.890 6673-6673/com.ablazephoenix.mycartoon W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 298: Landroid/app/Activity;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
08-25 01:24:56.890 6673-6673/com.ablazephoenix.mycartoon D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0151
08-25 01:24:56.890 6673-6673/com.ablazephoenix.mycartoon I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.dismissKeyboardShortcutsHelper, referenced from method com.ablazephoenix.mycartoon.CartoonActivity.access$super
08-25 01:24:56.890 6673-6673/com.ablazephoenix.mycartoon W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 168: Landroid/app/Activity;.dismissKeyboardShortcutsHelper ()V
08-25 01:24:56.890 6673-6673/com.ablazephoenix.mycartoon D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0157
08-25 01:24:56.890 6673-6673/com.ablazephoenix.mycartoon E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.ablazephoenix.mycartoon.CartoonActivity.access$super
08-25 01:24:56.890 6673-6673/com.ablazephoenix.mycartoon W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 296 (Landroid/os/PersistableBundle;) in Lcom/ablazephoenix/mycartoon/CartoonActivity;
08-25 01:24:56.890 6673-6673/com.ablazephoenix.mycartoon D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x01ba
08-25 01:24:56.890 6673-6673/com.ablazephoenix.mycartoon E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.media.session.MediaController', referenced from method com.ablazephoenix.mycartoon.CartoonActivity.access$super
```

**so guys, before I lose my my mind(!) please tell me what this error means? what can I do to resolve this problem?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem. This is perfectly normal behavior. It indicates that you have code that references classes or methods that do not exist on the version of Android that you are running on. So long as you do not *execute* any of that code, you are fine. If you *do* execute some of that code, you will crash, and LogCat will show a Java stack trace showing the source of the error.